# Starting an Expect script within an Expect script

Tags: expect

I am trying to run an Expect script within an Expect script (code below). However, I get the following error:

```
spawn ./script.exp
couldn't execute "./script.exp": no such file or directory
    while executing
"spawn "./script.exp""
    (file "./script.exp" line 7)
```

I have double checked and script.exp exists and is in the /home/user/scripts directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ssh user@192.168.2.1
expect "$"
send "cd /home/user/scripts\r"
expect "$"
spawn "./script.exp"
expect "$"
send "logout\r"
```

Comment: `spawn` starts a new process on your local machine. To start that script on the remote machine, use `send "./script.exp\r"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [the advice given in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34924035/starting-expect-script-within-expect-script#comment57582225_34924035), using `send "./script.exp\r"`
instead of `spawn "./script.exp"`, fixes the problem.